# WEB Service em Java

Tags: java, json, web-service, post, jax-rs

Estou criando uma Web Service, mas estou com muitas dúvidas de como receber o JSON na mesma como parâmetro.

```
@Path("WebService/{json}")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String  POST (@PathParam("json") String json) 
{
    return json ;
}
```

Nesse código estou recebendo o JSON na URL dessa forma:

```
http://localhost:8080/IC/webresources/WebService/[   {     "name": "SAM",     "id": 1   },   {     "name": "DEAN",     "id": 2   } ]
```

Ou seja, há um JSON na URL.

Essa é a única maneira que encontrei até agora. Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1):

Use `@FormParam` no lugar de `@PathParam`.

Com isso, você pode colocar o JSON no corpo da requisição, uma vez que isso é um POST.

Comment: Obrigado, Victor! Você tem algum exemplo de requisição? Desculpa é que é a minha primeira vez fazendo uma Web Service.

Answer (score -1):

você não precisa passar os parâmetros pela URL, já que se trata de um POST.

Veja o exemplo neste link https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/ na parte do POST.

Veja que o seu

> @Path("WebService/{json}")

será diferente, sem o json.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado, pela ajuda! Pelo que entendi ele recebeu e automaticamente converteu para objeto, mas no meu caso, eu preciso receber o JSON inteiro, sem converter ... tem alguma dica?